# Is there any function except Decode and IIF to implement case when statements in expression transformation in informatica powercenter?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Is there any function except Decode and IIF to implement case when statements in expression transformation in informatica powercenter?

I would really appreciate if anyone could give me some specific examples on the same.

Thanks much for your help!

Comment: Can you describe your ISSUE? This would help a lot. It would be far easier to recommend a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a router transformation instead. It behaves like a traditional case when i.e. you can have multi match. You just have to pipe each outcome separately